# Can we use a matrix as input for feedforward neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

I'm studying neural networks but haven't yet studied CNNs in depth.

*I'm wondering whether we can use a matrix as input for feedforward neural networks?
Or can we only use vectors as input for feedforward NNs?*

I'm asking this because in all the practical examples I've worked with I had to flatten the input matrix (for example images) to use it as an input in form of a vector.

Comment: Yes, of course. Most neural network libraries in fact accept tensors (sic). E.g. an image is usually a 3 dimensional array (3 rgb layers of 2d values).

Comment: Do you mean the theory or the software implementation?

Comment: @Dave I mean the software implementation.

Comment: @conjectures Is that also true for feedforward NNs? Or would we have to use a CNN architecture?

Comment: This is almost always true. In TF/Keras, which is what I know, one can pass in multiple multidimensional arrays (which cat pic is cuter?). Of course *using* fancy things gets more complicated but one can do it. (Also, I would say CNN is a feed forward network of a particular kind.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNNs for image recognition can take in not just a matrix but also a MxNx3 array (width, height, RGB channels). In fact, they can take in any array shape.